# Generic interface implementation - order of execution

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have the following generic interface

```
public interface ISerializer<T>
{
    MemoryStream Serialize(IList<T> list);
    MemoryStream Serialize(T obj);
}
```

When I implement the interface as follows

```
 ISerializer<IList<BarcodeScannerModel>> Serializer = new Serializer<IList<BarcodeScannerModel>>();
 var memstream = Serializer.Serialize(list);

 object myObject = new object();
 ISerializer<object> Serializer = new Serializer<object>();
 var memStr = Serializer .Serialize(myObject);
```

Both implementations use `MemoryStream Serialize(T obj);`

My question is why does the list version use the `MemoryStream Serialize(T obj);` 
and not the  `Serialize(IList<T> list);` version?

Comment: How is your `list` declared? It should be typed as `IList<T>` not `List<T>` or anything.

Comment: What is the type of `list`? It would really help if you'd provide a *complete* example here rather than just snippets.

Comment: `Serialize(IList<T> list);` expects an `IList<T>` so if T is an `IList<T>` then `MemoryStream Serialize(IList<T> list);` will only be called if you pass in an `Ilist<Ilist<T>>`

Comment: IList<BarcodeScannerModel>list = new List<BarcodeScannerModel>();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that your call to

```
var memstream = Serializer.Serialize(list);
```

is calling

```
MemoryStream Serialize(T obj);
```

is that when the generics are "filled out" your interface "looks like" (pseudocode):

```
public interface ISerializer<IList<BarcodeScannerModel>>
{
    MemoryStream Serialize(IList<IList<BarcodeScannerModel>> list);
    MemoryStream Serialize(IList<BarcodeScannerModel> obj);
}
```

and so when passing an `IList<BarcodeScannerModel>` to `Serialize()` it correctly chooses the `obj` overload (note that correctly does not equate to desired).

---

If you want it to call

```
MemoryStream Serialize(IList<T> list);
```

then you need to define your `serializer` like:

```
ISerializer<BarcodeScannerModel> serializer = new Serializer<BarcodeScannerModel>();
```

---

Basically you are doubling up on `IList`s

Comment: Ok, so I am passing in a list of T's so that list of  T's becomes the T in Serialize(T obj); and if I truly have a list of a list of T's then the other method would be called. Thanks, I get it.

Comment: Exactly! No problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
ISerializer<BarcodeScannerModel> Serializer = new ...
```

My guess is that because your interface method is defined for `List<T>` and in the same time you pass `List<Barcode...>` as `T`, your actual parameter is not of the expected type.